# Redireccionar a otra pagina despues de un formulario

Tags: php, html

He hecho una pagina que contiene un formulario hecho en PHP y HTML, para poder acceder a la pagina despues del formulario se deben de cumplir algunas restringiciones, 3 en concreto que son las siguientes: Elegir una profesion, la suma de 4 input type number debe de ser 40 exactos y por ultimo se deben seleccionar un minimo y un maximo de 3 checkboxes, no consigo acceder a la segunda pagina,creo que el error esta en el action de formulario, pero no se de que manera se puede hacer teniendo restricciones, no se que mas cambiar, aqui mi codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/style.css">
    <title>CREA TU PERSONAJE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>CREA TU PERSONAJE</legend>
                <form action="  <?php
                                    print (isset($_POST['fue'])
                                            &&
                                        isset($_POST['agi'])
                                            &&
                                        isset($_POST['def'])
                                            &&
                                        isset($_POST['vit'])
                                            &&
                                        ($_POST['fue'] + $_POST['agi'] + $_POST['def'] + $_POST['vit']) == 40 && isset($_POST['opcion[]']) && $_POST['opcion']== 3)  ? '../PHP/crear.php' : '';
                                ?>"
                      method="post">
                    <p>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" required></p>

                    <p>Profesion: <select name="select" required>
                        <option value="select" id="select">--SELECCIONA--</option>
                        <option value="Bárbaro">Bárbaro</option>
                        <option value="Bardo">Bardo</option>
                        <option value="Brujo">Brujo</option>
                        <option value="Clérigo">Clérigo</option>
                        <option value="Druida">Druida</option>
                        <option value="Explorador">Explorador</option>
                        <option value="Guerrero">Guerrero</option>
                        <option value="Hechicero">Hechicero</option>
                        <option value="Mago">Mago</option>
                        <option value="Monje">Monje</option>
                        <option value="Paladín">Paladín</option>
                        <option value="Pícaro">Pícaro</option>
                    </select></p>
                    <?php
                    if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
                        $select = $_POST['select'];
                        if ($select == "select") {
                            print "<p style='color: red'>¡Ups!: Elige una Profesión.</p>";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <p>Caracteristicas (La suma debe de ser 40):</p>
                    <p>FUE: <input type="number" min="0" max="40" name="fue" id="fue" required></p>
                    <p>AGI: <input type="number" min="0" max="40" name="agi" id="agi" required></p>
                    <p>DEF: <input type="number" min="0" max="40" name="def" id="def" required></p>
                    <p>VIT: <input type="number" min="0" max="40" name="vit" id="vit" required></p>

                    <?php
                    if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
                        $input1 = $_POST['fue'];
                        $input2 = $_POST['agi'];
                        $input3 = $_POST['def'];
                        $input4 = $_POST['vit'];

                        $suma = $input1 + $input2 + $input3 + $input4;

                        if ($suma !== 40) {
                            print "<p style='color: red'>¡Ups!: La suma debe ser igual a 40.</p>";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>

                    <p>Historia: <textarea name="history" id="texto" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea></p>

                    <p>Habilidades (Elegir 3 a elección): <br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Atletismo"> Atletismo ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Acrobacias"> Acrobacias ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Juego de manos"> Juego de manos ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Sigilo"> Sigilo ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Arcano"> Arcano ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Investigación"> Investigación ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Naturaleza"> Naturaleza ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Religión"> Religión ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Trato de Animales"> Trato de Animales <br><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Medicina"> Medicina ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Percepción"> Percepción ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Perspicacia"> Perspicacia ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Supervivencia"> Supervivencia ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Engaño"> Engaño ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Intimidación"> Intimidación ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Interpretación"> Interpretación ||
                        <input type="checkbox" name="opcion[]" value="Persuasión"> Persuasión
                      </p>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['opcion'])){
                        $opcionesSeleccionadas = $_POST['opcion'];
                        if(count($opcionesSeleccionadas) > 3 or count($opcionesSeleccionadas) < 3){
                            print "<p style='color: red'>¡Ups! Debes seleccionar 3 opciones.</p>";
                        }
                    }


                    ?>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar datos" name="submit"></p>
                </form>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué errores te da y que es lo que quieres hacer? Porque ya he revisado tu código y no le veo lógica al `action` ni en las "pseudocondicionales" que estas usando, además no es buena practica hacer eso. Si explicas un poco mejor pueda que te ayudemos más.